# Using Antipattern in Object Oriented Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

After reading an interesting article, I have a few questions around this. Please refer to *Common Pitfall #8: Pretending Java is more like C (i.e. not understanding OOP)* on [[zero-turn-around]](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/watch-out-for-these-10-common-pitfalls-of-experienced-java-developers-architects/)

I agree to the authors solution for the pitfall. I face a similar issue with my code (abuse of **instanceof**). But I cannot implement the code as the author has suggested. My scenario is as below

1. I have JMS as a messaging bus.
2. Messages float around the system. Listener typically listen to the messages.
3. All the messages have a single parent IMessage.
4. I use **instanceof** to distinguish between messages.
5. The listeners typically do domain specific business logic.

If I agree with the authors solution, I will have to implement domain specific business logic in the Message classes, which I think will bloat my light-weight message objects. Not just that, I will now have many references (composition) in my message objects which I think is unfair as the message objects will now have business (domain) behavior in it.

What is the reasonable solution to this problem? Example code below

```
public void onMessage(IMessage mssg)
{

    if(mssg instanceof MoPn){
       ...
    } else if(mssg instance of MoZn){
       ...
    } else if(mssg instance of MoLn){
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the matter with domain specific business logic in the Message classes?  Object orientation suggests a particular way to break the classes up.  But at the same time you desire to keep your message objects "light" and logic-free.  Those are conflicting goals.  I personally would not worry about putting business logic in the message.  After all, a message *means* a particular thing, what is wrong with putting the logic that corresponds to that meaning?  Adding logic (to class) does not make the message harder to transmit (the instance).  Otherwise, testing the class of an instance is OK.

Comment: @AgilePro Well, the problem is the list of "listeners" is ever growing. The listeners really do very specialized business logic. For example on receiving an ALARM message, an SNMP trap should be triggered. Also on receiving the alarm, a client specific representation must be calculated. If I start doing all this in the Alarm message, I am afraid the Alarm object is sooner going to be un-maintainable. Isn't this an anti pattern in itself?

Comment: Yes. There are a couple of cases where you want to ignore the advise to have logic selected by the class.  If the same messages are sent to different clients with different behaviors, you probably don't want to put the logic in the message class.  Also true if the message classes are standardize (shared) and you don't have the right to change them.  In those cases, simply testing the class of the instance is fine.  You could make a wrapper class to do this, but in principle it is no different.  The OOP style admonishment does not fit this case.

Comment: You could have a look on how this is handled in scala/akka for example. A more functional style with pattern matching is easier, more flexible then oo in this case. The functional patterns also apply in Java, but won't fit as nice as scala.

Comment: I am the author of the zeroturnaround article linked. My point on #8 is that some developers do not understand the difference between OOP and procedural. That is the antipattern (not understanding OOP). If you understand them both and you think that in your case procedural is better, then use it. You don't have to apply OOP everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reasonable solution is creating listeners that know to work with specific type of message.

Here is the interface.

```
interface MessageListener<M extends IMessage> {
    void onMessage(M message);
}
```

Here is a skeleton of one of the classes:

```
class MoZnListener implements MessageListener<MoZn> {
    public void onMessage(MoZn message) {
    }
}
```

Now you can create mapping between messages and listeners. You can use properties file, hard coded map, annotations. It is up to you. Once you have it you can implement one JMS message listener that looks like

```
class MessageEntryPoint implements MessageListener {
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        getMessageHandler(message).onMessage(message.getObject());
    }
}
```

Now your system is extandable. No instanceof. To introduce new message type you just have to create appropriate class that implements `IMessage` and listener that supports it.

BTW more comments.

1. Using `I` as to mark interface is not java-style.
2. I am not familiar with your domain and probably name like `MoPn` is self-explainable for you, but IMHO it is not. Try to use more self explainable identifiers.

Comment: Could you flesh out the `getMessageHandler` routine?  I believe that still requires calls to `instanceof` unless there is some magic I am not aware of.

Comment: I second your thoughts @AgilePro . I believe without instanceof, its not going to be possible to evaluate the message type.

Comment: getMessageHandler returns message handler for specific messages based on the mapping created. It might uses instance of, but only one, where it's used inside of loop that iterates the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

This might upset some purists, but I believe that using a language with OO features doesn't necessarily mean you have to apply OO to everything.

Messages are simply schema. They carry data. Forcing object-orientation upon structures that merely carry data from one place to another can be an anti-pattern as well.

Answer (score 0):

Separating the logic from the data model is sometimes seen as being against OOP but is sometimes necessary for decoupling. The code sending the message doesn't need to know anything about how to respond to the message.

Some of the other problems with instanceof are that it's hard to find what needs updating when adding a new type, and there's no way to make sure all cases are covered. These problems can be solved by adding some new interfaces:

```
interface Message {
    void callHandler(MessageHandler handler);
}

interface MessageHandler {
    default void onMoPn(MoPn message) {
    }

    default void onMoZn(MoZn message) {
    }
}

class MoPn implements Message {
    public void callHandler(MessageHandler handler) {
        handler.onMoPn(this);
    }
}

class Mozn implements Message {
    public void callHandler(MessageHandler handler) {
        handler.onMoZn(this);
    }
}
```

and add a handler:

```
class MessageHandlerImpl implements MessageHandler {
    public void onMoPn(MoPn message) {
        System.out.println("MoPn message: " + message);
    }
}
```

When you get a message, you can call the handler like:

```
MessageHandler handler = new MessageHandlerImpl()
Message message = new MoPn();

message.callHandler(handler);
```